# Update table column with different values

Tags: mysql

I would like to pick your brains to solve a problem since I am new to `MySQL` and cannot get past to it :(

I have a table named `"localgames"` and a column named `"Stock"`. The values into Stock are:

```
16Sold out
18Sold out
25Sold out
50Sold out
```

I want to transform this all in "Sold out" and I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE localgames SET Stock = IF(Stock REGEXP '*.Sold out', 'Sold out', Stock);
```

Also tried

```
UPDATE localgames SET Stock = IF(Stock REGEXP '^[0-9]Sold out', 'Sold out', Stock);
```

Nothing seems to work. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Try this:  update localgames SET Stock = "Sold Out" where ID = YourRowIDHere. The where clause is important otherwise it will update all the rows with name 'Sold Out'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks, we shouldn't accomplice it with `REPLACE` and also `REGEXP` of MySQL. But you can achieve your goals with this simple query. I hope it will help you.

```
UPDATE 
  localgames
SET 
  Stock = 'Sold out' 
WHERE 
  Stock LIKE '%Sold out';
```

Comment: Cool, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that. Your table design is not normalized.

A better approach would be to have a table like this

```
localgames
----------
id
name 
total_capacity (INT)
sold_capacity (INT)
```

Then you could find out if a game is sold out like this

```
select case when total_capacity - sold_capacity = 0 
            then 'sold out'
            else 'free places left'
       end as status
from localgames
```

Comment: I should have explained that I actually need to clean the table to be able to export to somewhere else, there is the reason I am trying to find a way to update everything that is "XXSold out" to "Sold out" only. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi @RafaelSouza, Please refer to my answer. I hope it will help you to reach your goal.